# Conditional Wordpress Header

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a header to be used in my WP posts so that it displays a list item and and anchor according to the post's author. For example, if, and only if, the author has ID of 6, the header will have one more list item with an anchor to, let's say, page A. If it's not that author I don't want it to display the list item.

So in my **single-post.php** template I load this header I want with:

```
<?php get_header('bananas'); ?>
```

and in **header-bananas.php** I have:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Clinic's Blog</a></li>
        <?php if (!is_author(6)){ ?>
            <li id="apples"><a href="#">Link to page A</a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

However I suspect Wordpress is not looping in the header so it can't detect if the conditional is true before loading the post in single-post.php, because #apples is displaying even if that post isn't written by author of id 6.

Am I right? If so, what's the best approach to load a conditional with a Wordpress function in the header? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong function.

The correct way of doing this would be something like this:

```
<?php
  $myauthor = get_the_author_ID($post->ID);
    if ($myauthor == 6){
      echo '<li id="apples"><a href="#">Link to Page A</a></li>';
    };
?>
```